# Defining Global Variables

Tags: python, scope, global-variables

I was just wondering, in python 3, why do some global variables have to be defined as `global` every singe function you use (that you're defining), but others only need to be be defined once? Probably a question because I haven't understood scope properly, please could someone shed some light?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Variables in a scope can be *read* but not modified by functions/objects declared within that scope. If you also wish to change their value, you have to declare them as global.

UPDATE: However, please note, that "changing the value" may or may not mean what you are eventually used to if comming from other programming languages, as assignment in Python means giving an object a name. The keyword `global` allows you to let the given *name* to point to (being associated with) a different object. Look at the following example:

```
aa = 1
bb = 2
cc = [ 1, 2, 3 ]

def test():
    global aa
    aa = -1
    bb = -1
    cc[2] = -1

test()
print "aa:", aa
print "bb:", bb
print "cc:", cc
```

would result in:

```
aa: -1
bb: 2
cc: [1, 2, -1]
```

- In the function `test()` the name `aa` is declared as `global`, so `aa = -1` in the function would cause to point the *global* name `aa` to a new object, namely the integer `-1`.
- The name `bb` in `test()` is not declared as global, therefore the assignment `bb = -1` 
  would create the name `bb` locally within the function and point it to `-1`, while leaving the name `bb` in the *global* scope still pointing to the value `2`.
- Variable `cc` is also not declared as global, therefore, you can't change the association of the *global* `cc` in the function `test()`. However, since in the global scope `cc` is associated with a *mutable* object, you can change the content of this object within the function.

Note, that the formulation here is maybe not the official Python way of explaining the differences, but it may help to understand things if you have some background in other programming languages.

Comment: Note that the correct interpretation of this depends entirely on the correct interpretation of "change the value of a variable". History shows that beginners frequently get that part wrong.

Comment: I agree, I find therefore the thread you linked in above a very good  starting point about clarifying the fine details (with respect of mutable an immutable types).

Comment: That you mention mutable and immutable types as if there was a distinction makes it sound like you don't understand it either.

Comment: Sorry, if my formulation was misunderstandable. I've made the experience, that people comming from other programming languages often have difficulties to understand, why mutable and inmutable types behave differently, if they try to explain things with their experiences made in other programming languges. I agree, that if you once know how Python works, their behaviour is consistent. I now tried to explain this somewhat more in detail above.

Comment: What I'm talking about is that they don't behave differently at all.